# tidy eval map over column names

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, tidyeval

I have made my own function as follows:

```
    emp_term_var <- function(data, colName, year = "2015") {
  
  # Terminations by year and variable in df
  colName <- enquo(colName) 
  term_test <- data %>%
    filter(year(DateofTermination) == year) %>%
    group_by(UQ(colName)) %>%
    count(UQ(colName)) %>%
    clean_names()
  return(term_test)
  
}
```

I have a df with multiple columns such as Department, State, Position etc. WHen I want to use the function I have written I put the name of the column without quotations as follows:

```
emp_term_var(data = df, colName = Department, year = "2015")
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   department [5]
  department               n
  <chr>                <int>
1 Admin Offices            1
2 IT/IS                    4
3 Production              15
4 Sales                    1
5 Software Engineering     2
>
```

How can I map over mulitple columns? if I try

```
columns <- c(Department, State)
```

R does not lelt me as it identifies these as objects and not column names. How can I make R know that these are column names to be stored in the object columns so I can pass it to map in this form:

```
map(colnames, ~ emp_term_var(df, colName = .x, year = "2015"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `enquo` change it to either `.data` or convert to symbols with `ensym` and evaluate (`!!`)

```
emp_term_var <- function(data, colName, year = "2015") {
  
  # Terminations by year and variable in df
  colName <- ensym(colName) 
  term_test <- data %>%
    filter(year(DateofTermination) == year) %>%
    #group_by(!!colName)) %>%
    count(!!(colName)) %>%
    clean_names()
  return(term_test)
  
}
```

NOTE: `count` can take the column without any grouping as well

The advantage with `ensym` route is that it can both quoted and unquoted input i.e. it takes the string as column names and without the quotes

```
nm1 <- c("Department", "State")
purrr::map(nm1, ~ emp_term_var(df, colName = !!.x, year = "2015"))
```

or if we want to use

```
emp_term_var(data = df, colName = Department, year = "2015")
```

Or can take

```
emp_term_var(data = df, colName = "Department", year = "2015")
```

Comment: Excellent thank you so much for your support I have learned a lot :)

Comment: Hi Akrun. I see you regularly mentioning quoted and unquoted inputs as an advantage of `ensym()`. It's true that `ensym()` copies the interface of the LHS of `=`, where both `foo = bar` and `"foo" = bar` are allowed. However this has a downside, supplying quoted inputs might give the wrong impression that the argument is not data-masked and you can supply a normal variable instead. I would only ever use the quotes with non-syntactic names like `"foo bar !"`. I guess my point is that I think it would be better not to mention this "feature" at all since it might be misleading.

Comment: Akrun, your post inspired me to look for better solutions: https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/issues/1300

Answer (score 6):

Another solution is to keep your function as is but change the way you call it inside `map()`:

```
columns <- c("Department", "State")

map(colnames, ~ emp_term_var(df, colName = .data[[.x]], year = "2015"))
```

Note how we pass `colName = .data[[.x]]` instead of `colName = .x`.

You can also do this in other contexts like a `for` loop:

```
for (col in columns) {
  print(
    emp_term_var(df, colName = .data[[col]], year = "2015")
  )
}
```